# Converting FlowDocument to XPS messes up page contents

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to convert a `FlowDocument` to XPS. Here is how the `FlowDocument` is defined:

```xml
<FlowDocument PageHeight="29.7cm" PageWidth="21cm" PagePadding="2cm,2cm,2cm,2cm">
                    
</FlowDocument>
```

It is inside a `RichTextBox` and is populated by a user. It is saved as a `.rtf` file (`.xaml`gave me the same results).
Here is the method I am using to save the doc:

```cs
public void UploadTemplate(TextRange content, string filename)
{
   string destPath = Path.Combine(default_template_path, filename + ".rtf");

   if (content.CanSave(DataFormats.Rtf))
   {
      using (var stream = new FileStream(destPath, FileMode.Create))
      {
         content.Save(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
         stream.Close();
      }
   }    
}
```

And here is how I load the doc:

```cs
public void LoadTemplate(string template_path, TextRange content)
{
   if (content.CanLoad(DataFormats.Rtf))
   {
      using (var stream = new FileStream(template_path, FileMode.Open))
      {
         content.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
         stream.Close();
      }
   }
}
```

Finally this is the code I use for converting the `FlowDocument` to `XPS`:

```cs
public static MemoryStream FlowDocumentToXPS(FlowDocument flowDocument)
{
   MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
   using (Package package = Package.Open(stream, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
   {
      using (XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.Maximum))
      {
         XpsSerializationManager rsm = new XpsSerializationManager(new XpsPackagingPolicy(xpsDoc), false);
         DocumentPaginator paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)flowDocument).DocumentPaginator;
         paginator.PageSize = new Size(flowDocument.PageWidth, flowDocument.PageHeight);
         rsm.SaveAsXaml(paginator);
         rsm.Commit();
       }
   }
   stream.Position = 0;
   Console.WriteLine(stream.Length);
   Console.WriteLine(stream.Position);
   return stream;
}
```

After saving this stream to a `.xps` file the document pages seem like they are divided in 2 columns. This is what I get from that export:

[image]

Can someone help me figure this out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that might stumble upon this. You must set the `FlowDocument.ColumnWidth` property when converting to `XPS`. In this case it would need to be something like this:

```cs
public static MemoryStream FlowDocumentToXPS(FlowDocument flowDocument)
{
   flowDocument.ColumnWidth = (int)YourColumnWidth; // THIS IS THE KEY LINE

   MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
   using (Package package = Package.Open(stream, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
   {
      using (XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.Maximum))
      {
         XpsSerializationManager rsm = new XpsSerializationManager(new XpsPackagingPolicy(xpsDoc), false);
         DocumentPaginator paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)flowDocument).DocumentPaginator;
         paginator.PageSize = new Size(flowDocument.PageWidth, flowDocument.PageHeight);
         rsm.SaveAsXaml(paginator);
         rsm.Commit();
       }
   }
   stream.Position = 0;
   Console.WriteLine(stream.Length);
   Console.WriteLine(stream.Position);
   return stream;
}
```